# How can I reduce the docker image size

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image by using below docker codes, after building it  the image size is 1.70G.
Can any technique be used to reduce the Docker image size?

Note: I'm trying to build a docker image to use 'JDBC Foreign Data Wrapper for PostgreSQL'

```
FROM postgres:15-bullseye

# Copy service script
# Install DB drivers
COPY drivers/ /usr/share/java/

# Script is called after postgres is started
COPY entrypoint-deb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Copy JDBC FDW library to the postgres contfib dir
COPY jdbc_fdw /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw

COPY ./halo-my-db/ /halo-my-db/

# Install Packages
# Install flask for service controls server
# Setup private key for halo-mdm-db repository
# Download startup scripts repository files


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk build-essential postgresql-server-dev-all --no-install-recommends && \
    cd /halo-mdm-db/ &&  \
    chown -R postgres:postgres /halo-mdm-db && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib/libjvm.so && \
    export USE_PGXS=1 && \
    export PATH=\"/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin:$PATH\" && \
    cd /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw && \
    make clean && make install && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove && \
    apt-get remove -y wget unzip && \
    apt-get remove -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt-get remove -y build-essential && \
    apt-get remove -y postgresql-server-dev-all && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /halo-my-db/
```

Comment: Without your source repository there are a number of things we can't test, but it's possible that using a [multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) might help. Compile and install your project in the first stage, then copy it into place in the second stage. In your final stage you won't need to install any of the `-dev` requirements, etc.

Comment: It looks like you are installing dev tools (java source, jdk, make, etc) into a postgres image, then build what I assume is some sort of driver? If so, then as @larsks says you would be better to do that build work in a separate stage and then just copy the built artifact into the postgres image.

Comment: I thought to use multi-stage-build, however I'm not able to put in practical approach.
Yes, I'm installing dev-tools (java source, jdk, make, etc), however I'm removing those in same layer.
I'm using  Postgres source code and compiling **https://github.com/pgspider/jdbc_fdw**
@larsks

Answer (score 0):

The base `postgres:15-bullseye` image is 379mb, so the extra 1.3gb of data must  from the installed packages (and their removal too) and whatever you copy into the image from your local host. I expect the installed packages are the bulk of it.
You can split your Dockerfile into a *build* component where you add in all the stuff you need to make/package `jdbc_fdw`, and then in the 'final' image copy that packaged `jdbc_fdw` from the *build* image into the *final* image.

You can do something like that shown below. Use a BUILD image where you install the development tools required and the source code to build. Then do the build. You then start with another `postgres:15-bullseye` image, copy in what you need from your local machine/context and copy *the built jdbc_fdw* folder from the *BUILD* image.

```
FROM postgres:15-bullseye AS BUILD 

# Copy JDBC FDW library to the postgres contfib dir
COPY jdbc_fdw /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw

# Install Packages
# Install flask for service controls server
# Setup private key for halo-mdm-db repository
# Download startup scripts repository files

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk build-essential postgresql-server-dev-all --no-install-recommends && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib/libjvm.so && \
    export USE_PGXS=1 && \
    export PATH=\"/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin:$PATH\" && \
    cd /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw && \
    make clean && make install

# No need to cleanup in the build image ...

# Now make the final image, copying in the jdbc_fdw stuff we built in the BUILD image,
# and the other stuff from our local context.
FROM postgres:15-bullseye

# Copy service script
# Install DB drivers
COPY drivers/ /usr/share/java/

# Script is called after postgres is started
COPY entrypoint-deb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

# Copy JDBC FDW library to the postgres contfib dir
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw /usr/share/postgresql/15/contrib/jdbc_fdw

COPY ./halo-my-db/ /halo-my-db/
```